# How can I view weights in a .tflite file?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

I get the pre-trained .pb file of MobileNet and find it's not quantized while the fully quantized model should be converted into .tflite format. Since I'm not familiar with tools for mobile app developing, how can I get the fully quantized weights of MobileNet from .tflite file. More precisely, how can I extract quantized    parameters and view its numerical values ?

Answer (score 11):

The Netron model viewer has nice view and export of data, as well as a nice network diagram view.
https://github.com/lutzroeder/netron

Answer (score 8):

I'm also in the process of studying how TFLite works. What I found may not be the best approach and I would appreciate any expert opinions. Here's what I found so far using `flatbuffer` python API.

First you'll need to compile the schema with flatbuffer. The output will be a folder called `tflite`.

`flatc --python tensorflow/contrib/lite/schema/schema.fbs`

Then you can load the model and get the tensor you want. `Tensor` has a method called `Buffer()` which is, according to the schema,

> An index that refers to the buffers table at the root of the model.

So it points you to the location of the data.

```
from tflite import Model
buf = open('/path/to/mode.tflite', 'rb').read()
model = Model.Model.GetRootAsModel(buf, 0)
subgraph = model.Subgraphs(0)
# Check tensor.Name() to find the tensor_idx you want
tensor = subgraph.Tensors(tensor_idx) 
buffer_idx = tensor.Buffer()
buffer = model.Buffers(buffer_idx)
```

After that you'll be able to read the data by calling `buffer.Data()`

Reference:
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/contrib/lite/schema/schema.fbs
https://github.com/google/flatbuffers/tree/master/samples

Comment: in the `schema.fbs file`, there is a Table called `Model` which has a field called `description`.  I would like to write a string (let's say a one-liner model description) to this field.  How can I then load a tflite model, and update the tflite file with this additional metadata ?Appreciate some assistance.

Answer (score 8):

Using TensorFlow 2.0, you can extract the weights and some information regarding the tensor (shape, dtype, name, quantization) with the following script - inspired from [TensorFlow documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/guide/inference)

```
import tensorflow as tf
import h5py


# Load TFLite model and allocate tensors.
interpreter = tf.lite.Interpreter(model_path="v3-large_224_1.0_uint8.tflite")
interpreter.allocate_tensors()

# Get input and output tensors.
input_details = interpreter.get_input_details()
output_details = interpreter.get_output_details()


# get details for each layer
all_layers_details = interpreter.get_tensor_details() 


f = h5py.File("mobilenet_v3_weights_infos.hdf5", "w")   

for layer in all_layers_details:
     # to create a group in an hdf5 file
     grp = f.create_group(str(layer['index']))

     # to store layer's metadata in group's metadata
     grp.attrs["name"] = layer['name']
     grp.attrs["shape"] = layer['shape']
     # grp.attrs["dtype"] = all_layers_details[i]['dtype']
     grp.attrs["quantization"] = layer['quantization']

     # to store the weights in a dataset
     grp.create_dataset("weights", data=interpreter.get_tensor(layer['index']))


 f.close()
```

Comment: Looks like the tflite assigns the index to a layer not in the same order as the layers are sequenced in the model. Instead, it sorts the list of layers by name and then assigns the indexes to the sorted list. So how do you recover the correct layer sequence? Any workaround for that? (I am working with the quantized Mobilenetv2 model)

Answer (score 0):

You can view it using Netron app
macOS: Download the .dmg file or run brew install netron

Linux: Download the .AppImage file or run snap install netron

Windows: Download the .exe installer or run winget install netron

Browser: Start the browser version.

Python Server: Run pip install netron and netron [FILE] or netron.start('[FILE]').