# Dumping Weights in TensorflowLite

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-lite, quantization

new Tensorflow 2.0 user. My project requires me to investigate the weights for the neural network i created in Tensorflow (super simple one). I think I know how to do it in the regular Tensorflow case. Namely I use the command model.save_weights(filename). I would like to repeat this effort for a .tflite model but I am having trouble. Instead of generating my own tensorflow lite model, I am using one of the many models which are provided online: https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/guide/hosted_model to avoid having to troubleshoot my use of the Tensorflow Lite converter. Any thoughts?

Comment: I think your question is similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52111699/how-can-i-view-weights-in-a-tflite-file

Comment: Perfect! Thanks Thaink!