# How to get weights in tflite using c++ api?

Tags: tensorflow-lite

I am using a .tflite model on device. The last layer is ConditionalRandomField layer, and I need weights of the layer to do prediction.
How do I get weights with c++ api?

related: [How can I view weights in a .tflite file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52111699/how-can-i-view-weights-in-a-tflite-file)

Netron or flatc doesn't meet my needs. too heavy on device.

It seems TfLiteNode stores weights in void* user_data or void* builtin_data. How do I read them?

**UPDATE:**

Conclusion: .tflite doesn't store CRF weights while .h5 dose. (Maybe because they  do not affect output.)

**WHAT I DO:**

```
// obtain from model.
Interpreter *interpreter;
// get the last index of nodes.
// I'm not sure if the index sequence of nodes is the direction which tensors or layers flows.
const TfLiteNode *node = &((interpreter->node_and_registration(interpreter->nodes_size()-1))->first);

// then follow the answer of @yyoon
```

Comment: The weights of a layer in a .tflite model are fixed, so normally you don't need to read those weights at runtime on device. Could you explain a bit more about why you need this?

Comment: @yyoon In Named Entity Recognition task,  ConditionalRandomField layer has  weights that doesn't affect the output but do affect the best path. Without CRF

Comment: So my question was really about why you need to read the values "at runtime" using the TFLite API. Could you read the weights from the .tflite model ahead of time, and just bake those values in your application to do the prediction?

Comment: @yyoon  Without CRF weights, I could only use [max(P(i))] as the NER label. With CRF weights, viterbi algorithm will be applied on the output to get the best path of labels. Currently, I save CRF weight as .txt along with .tflite when training. But I think it's a bad practice. "read the weights from the .tflite model ahead of time" not from training is what I am asking for.

Comment: Makes sense. Please see my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a TFLite node, the weights should be stored in the `inputs` array, which contains the index of the corresponding `TfLiteTensor*`.

So, if you have already obtained the `TfLiteNode*` of the last layer, you could do something like this to read the weight values.

```cpp
TfLiteContext* context; // You would usually have access to this already.
TfLiteNode* node;       // <obtain this from the graph>;

for (int i = 0; i < node->inputs->size; ++i) {
  TfLiteTensor* input_tensor = GetInput(context, node, i);

  // Determine if this is a weight tensor.
  // Usually the weights will be memory-mapped read-only tensor
  // directly baked in the TFLite model (flatbuffer).
  if (input_tensor->allocation_type == kTfLiteMmapRo) {
    // Read the values from input_tensor, based on its type.
    // For example, if you have float weights,
    const float* weights = GetTensorData<float>(input_tensor);

    // <read the weight values...>
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. GetTensorData works. Your explaination about TfLiteTensor and TfLiteNode makes the tflite structure more clear to me. By the way, I wonder how you learned those. TFLITE doc says little about the funtions or rules like "Usually the weights will be memory-mapped read-only tensor"?

Comment: Glad it helped! What I did was to answer was (1) I've used the netron tool (https://github.com/lutzroeder/netron) to open the mobilenet_v1 model, and checked where the weights are. They were listed in the inputs. (2) To confirm, I skimmed the conv2D op implementation (https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/lite/kernels/conv.cc#L938) and confirmed that it was reading the weights (filter, bias) from the input tensor and using GetTensorData().