# How to get output tensor from a specific layer?

Tags: android, tensorflow-lite

I would like to figure it out if is it possible to get the output from a specific layer using tensorflow lite for android environment.
At the moment I know that using: 'interpreter.run()' we take the "standard" output, but this is not what I'm looking for.
Thanks for any advice.

Comment: Currently, I don't think there is a way to do this. When an inference run is finished, the intermediate output you're interested in may or may not be available in memory, because TFLite aggressively tries to reuse earlier used tensor memory in later stages. What is your use case exactly?

Comment: Could you explain me better the part when you said that Tflite reuse earlier used tensor?
I asked this questione because I need to get the output from different layer of the network for some experiments on mobile environment.
I saw that the interpreter object has the method "getOutputTensor(int index)" that in theory (because I can't find the API for an explanation) gives the tensor at a specified index but I don't really understood how it works...

Comment: Sure. For the sake of explanation, let's simplify and say the graph has 4 nodes executed in sequence: input -> A -> B -> C -> D -> output. By the time you execute the C node, the output of A was already consumed by B and thus no longer needed in memory. Thus, the memory used for storing the output of A could be reused for storing the output of C node. After the inference is fully run, you can't get A's output because it's already overwritten by another node's output. See this comment: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/lite/arena_planner.h#L40-L42

Comment: So there is no way to get the output, for example, from the node C?

Comment: It is technically possible by getting the TfLiteNode object of the particular node, and then inspect the outputs. See my recent answer on a similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62015028/922135. In your case, you would want to inspect the outputs. But again, please be aware that the value you're reading may not be the correct values if later overwritten by other layers.

Comment: But in order to do this I need to use the C++ API, right? Is there a way to do that in Java?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think the functionality is exposed in Java API, as it's something you wouldn't normally need to do.

Comment: Ok, thank you really much, appreciate!

Comment: Where could I find the C++ api?

Comment: See https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/guide/android#build_c_libraries for C++ API build instructions for Android, and https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/api_docs/cc for the API reference documentation.

Comment: Sorry to bother you again, but I have a question, in your first comment you said that when an inference run is finished, the intermediate output could not be available in memory. And with this I understood why, but, instead, is there a way not to do a complete inference run, but a run that finish at the intermediate layer at which I want to extract the tensor? Or are the same thing?

Comment: No, there's no way to partially execute your model. It might be better to use regular TF instead of TFLite for your needs. Any reason for using TFLite specifically?

Comment: I need Tflite because I would like to do some experiments in a mobile environment, and for this purpose I need those tensors taken from specific layer. Do you know another way to accomplish this?

Comment: If using TF is really not your option, I don't think there is an easy way to do. You could modify the TFLite source code and build your own custom TFLite to achieve it, but I'm afraid that I wouldn't be able to help with that process.

Comment: Well, basic Tf could be an option if there is a way to integrate it in the mobile environment

Comment: Hi, again, I'm sorry but I don't understand how to configure my android project to use the tensorflow lite c++ api, have you got any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

@Simo I will write here a workaround of this problem. How about saving the part of the model you want to .tflite file. Let me explain myself. Instead of doing below and save the whole model:

```
# WHOLE MODEL
tflite_model = tf.keras.models.load_model('face_recog.weights.best.hdf5')
converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_keras_model(tflite_model)
tflite_save = converter.convert()
open("face_recog.tflite", "wb").write(tflite_save)
```

You can print the layers of your keras model:

```
print([layer.name for layer in keras_model.layers])
Output:
['anchor', 'positive', 'negative', 'model', 'lambda']

print([layer.name for layer in keras_model.get_layer('model').layers])
Output:  
['input_1', 'Conv1_pad', 'Conv1', 'bn_Conv1', 'Conv1_relu', 'expanded_conv_depthwise', 'expanded_conv_depthwise_BN', 'expanded_conv_depthwise_relu', 'expanded_conv_project', 'expanded_conv_project_BN', 'block_1_expand', 'block_1_expand_BN', 'block_1_expand_relu', 'block_1_pad', 'block_1_depthwise', 'block_1_depthwise_BN', 'block_1_depthwise_relu', 'block_1_project', 'block_1_project_BN', 'block_2_expand', 'block_2_expand_BN', 'block_2_expand_relu', 'block_2_depthwise', 'block_2_depthwise_BN', 'block_2_depthwise_relu', 'block_2_project', 'block_2_project_BN', 'block_2_add', 'block_3_expand', 'block_3_expand_BN', 'block_3_expand_relu', 'block_3_pad', 'block_3_depthwise', 'block_3_depthwise_BN', 'block_3_depthwise_relu', 'block_3_project', 'block_3_project_BN', 'block_4_expand', 'block_4_expand_BN', 'block_4_expand_relu', 'block_4_depthwise', 'block_4_depthwise_BN', 'block_4_depthwise_relu', 'block_4_project', 'block_4_project_BN', 'block_4_add', 'block_5_expand', 'block_5_expand_BN', 'block_5_expand_relu', 'block_5_depthwise', 'block_5_depthwise_BN', 'block_5_depthwise_relu', 'block_5_project', 'block_5_project_BN', 'block_5_add', 'block_6_expand', 'block_6_expand_BN', 'block_6_expand_relu', 'block_6_pad', 'block_6_depthwise', 'block_6_depthwise_BN', 'block_6_depthwise_relu', 'block_6_project', 'block_6_project_BN', 'block_7_expand', 'block_7_expand_BN', 'block_7_expand_relu', 'block_7_depthwise', 'block_7_depthwise_BN', 'block_7_depthwise_relu', 'block_7_project', 'block_7_project_BN', 'block_7_add', 'block_8_expand', 'block_8_expand_BN', 'block_8_expand_relu', 'block_8_depthwise', 'block_8_depthwise_BN', 'block_8_depthwise_relu', 'block_8_project', 'block_8_project_BN', 'block_8_add', 'block_9_expand', 'block_9_expand_BN', 'block_9_expand_relu', 'block_9_depthwise', 'block_9_depthwise_BN', 'block_9_depthwise_relu', 'block_9_project', 'block_9_project_BN', 'block_9_add', 'block_10_expand', 'block_10_expand_BN', 'block_10_expand_relu', 'block_10_depthwise', 'block_10_depthwise_BN', 'block_10_depthwise_relu', 'block_10_project', 'block_10_project_BN', 'block_11_expand', 'block_11_expand_BN', 'block_11_expand_relu', 'block_11_depthwise', 'block_11_depthwise_BN', 'block_11_depthwise_relu', 'block_11_project', 'block_11_project_BN', 'block_11_add', 'block_12_expand', 'block_12_expand_BN', 'block_12_expand_relu', 'block_12_depthwise', 'block_12_depthwise_BN', 'block_12_depthwise_relu', 'block_12_project', 'block_12_project_BN', 'block_12_add', 'block_13_expand', 'block_13_expand_BN', 'block_13_expand_relu', 'block_13_pad', 'block_13_depthwise', 'block_13_depthwise_BN', 'block_13_depthwise_relu', 'block_13_project', 'block_13_project_BN', 'block_14_expand', 'block_14_expand_BN', 'block_14_expand_relu', 'block_14_depthwise', 'block_14_depthwise_BN', 'block_14_depthwise_relu', 'block_14_project', 'block_14_project_BN', 'block_14_add', 'block_15_expand', 'block_15_expand_BN', 'block_15_expand_relu', 'block_15_depthwise', 'block_15_depthwise_BN', 'block_15_depthwise_relu', 'block_15_project', 'block_15_project_BN', 'block_15_add', 'block_16_expand', 'block_16_expand_BN', 'block_16_expand_relu', 'block_16_depthwise', 'block_16_depthwise_BN', 'block_16_depthwise_relu', 'block_16_project', 'block_16_project_BN', 'Conv_1', 'Conv_1_bn', 'out_relu', 'global_average_pooling2d', 'predictions', 'dense', 'dense_1']
```

And then you can take whatever layer you want from your model and save it to .tflite:

```
# PART OF MODEL
tflite_model = tf.keras.models.load_model('face_recog.weights.best.hdf5')
converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_keras_model(tflite_model.get_layer('model'))
tflite_save = converter.convert()
open("face_recog.tflite", "wb").write(tflite_save)
```

So using the above code the .tflite file will have input tensor = "input_1" and output = "dense_1"

Then inside android you have to use inputs for the specific layer "model" and you will get outputs of the specific shape as when you print the output details in python:

```
interpreter = tf.lite.Interpreter('face_recog.tflite')
print(interpreter.get_output_details())
interpreter.get_tensor_details()
```

Android part:

```
// Initialize interpreter
@Throws(IOException::class)
private suspend fun initializeInterpreter(app: Application) = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
    // Load the TF Lite model from asset folder and initialize TF Lite Interpreter without NNAPI enabled.
    val assetManager = app.assets
    val model = loadModelFile(assetManager, "face_recog_model_layer.tflite")
    val options = Interpreter.Options()
    options.setUseNNAPI(false)
    interpreter = Interpreter(model, options)
    // Reads type and shape of input and output tensors, respectively.
    val imageTensorIndex = 0
    val imageShape: IntArray =
        interpreter.getInputTensor(imageTensorIndex).shape() 
    Log.i("INPUT_TENSOR_WHOLE", Arrays.toString(imageShape))
    val imageDataType: DataType =
        interpreter.getInputTensor(imageTensorIndex).dataType()
    Log.i("INPUT_DATA_TYPE", imageDataType.toString())
    val probabilityTensorIndex = 0
    val probabilityShape: IntArray =
        interpreter.getOutputTensor(probabilityTensorIndex).shape()
    Log.i("OUTPUT_TENSOR_SHAPE", Arrays.toString(probabilityShape))
    val probabilityDataType: DataType =
        interpreter.getOutputTensor(probabilityTensorIndex).dataType()
    Log.i("OUTPUT_DATA_TYPE", probabilityDataType.toString())
    Log.i(TAG, "Initialized TFLite interpreter.")

}

@Throws(IOException::class)
private fun loadModelFile(assetManager: AssetManager, filename: String): MappedByteBuffer {
    val fileDescriptor = assetManager.openFd(filename)
    val inputStream = FileInputStream(fileDescriptor.fileDescriptor)
    val fileChannel = inputStream.channel
    val startOffset = fileDescriptor.startOffset
    val declaredLength = fileDescriptor.declaredLength
    return fileChannel.map(FileChannel.MapMode.READ_ONLY, startOffset, declaredLength)
}
```

I hope this will help someone. And of course if you need anything else tag me :)

Comment: Hi, I don't think that this solution may fit my problem, because I need to dinamically choose from which layer extract the output

Comment: Hi, Simo. Take a look at this page. Maybe you find an answer https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/performance/delegates

Comment: Thanks but at the moment i'm trying to figure it out on how to use the c++ api for Tflite but I really dont understand, I installed tensorflow using pip command, and bazel following the instruction but it gives me errors when launching bazel command, could you help me?

Comment: Sorry Simo, I haven't played with Basel. I hope you succeed in this soon!