# How to split a tflite file for cnn network into tflite files for each layer?

Tags: python, tensorflow-lite, face-recognition

I'm currently trying to find a way to get intermediate features for each layer of CNN network while running on the Android Stuio (java).
Actually, I found some related question and answer in the link below.

[How to get output tensor from a specific layer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62045028/how-to-get-output-tensor-from-a-specific-layer?newreg=743f7683b7394bd7b01d9d5ec6327e55)

From the above link, i think dividing the model by layer will be the only method for solving my task.
However, there isn't a solution about splitting .tffile to several .tffiles.

To be more precisely,

- The files I have: tflite file for mobilefacenet network
- The files that I have to make : tflite files for each layer of mobilefacenet

I will really appreciate if you can tell me the exact python code for doing above task.
Thanks a lot!

Below code is the part of my android studio java code related to this question.

```
/** Model loader **/
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
private void loadModel() {
    try {
        //model name
        String modelFile = "mobile_face_net.tflite";
        tfLite = new Interpreter(loadModelFile(MainActivity.this, modelFile));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private MappedByteBuffer loadModelFile(AppCompatActivity activity, String MODEL_FILE) throws IOException {
    AssetFileDescriptor fileDescriptor = activity.getAssets().openFd(MODEL_FILE);
    FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(fileDescriptor.getFileDescriptor());
    FileChannel fileChannel = inputStream.getChannel();
    long startOffset = fileDescriptor.getStartOffset();
    long declaredLength = fileDescriptor.getDeclaredLength();
    return fileChannel.map(FileChannel.MapMode.READ_ONLY, startOffset, declaredLength);
}
```

```
tfLite.runForMultipleInputsOutputs(inputArray, outputMap); //Run model
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "making tflite for each layer of mobilefacenet" ?

Comment: For example, assume that mobilefacenet is made of 3 layers; Layer1, Layer2, and Layer3.
Then the data flow will be shown as below.
Input --> Layer 1 --> Output of Layer 1 --> Layer 2 --> Output of Layer 2 --> Layer 3 ---> Output.

Since my ultimate goal is to get Output of Layer 1 and 2 (Intermediate features) on the android studio, I decided to make split the target network to several network.

Comment: I am not sure if that is possible, at least I haven't seen any android example that does that. But to me that seems a problem in ML side (python) not android or java, since the run of a .tflite model in android is similar for every model, you just need to know the input and the output format. So my suggestion is ask another question and use different tags, like "machine learning" "python" etc...

Comment: No issue, you can just update the tags of this question so you don't have duplicate questions

Answer (score 0):

There is an easier way to get layer by layer output. The API from python is this option

experimental_preserve_all_tensors

```
interpreter = tf.lite.Interpreter(
    model_path="test.tflite",
    experimental_preserve_all_tensors=True)
```

Now you can inspect layer by layer on this interpreter.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!
However, in my case, I have to define the interpreter in android studio using java rather than in python because I have to use that interpreter in android studio.
So, I think I can only use python for splitting the original tflite file.